# Using a Regex against a simple list with `ElemMatch` in MongoDB .NET

Tags: mongodb-.net-driver

Given a document with a list of strings, how would you assemble a C# MongoDB query to regex against each list item?

For example, here's some data.

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "4ded270ab29e220de8935c7b"
  },
  // ... some other stuff ...
  "categories": [
    {
      "Some Category",
      "Another Category",
      "Yet Another Category",
      "One Last Category"
    }
  ]
},
```

Ultimately, how would I structure a query like this that could be strongly-typed through the MonoDB LINQ provider?

```
{ "categories": { $elemMatch: { $regex: someSearch, $options: "i" } } }
```

I'm trying to make this work with `ElemMatch`, but I can't seem to structure a BsonRegularExpression to work with that method. If the data was a list of keyed elements, it looks like I could make this work for some key, say `itemName`.

```
// Doesn't translate to a list of raw strings.
Query.ElemMatch ("categories", Query.Match("itemName", new BsonRegularExpression (new Regex (someSearch, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)));
```

As soon as I try to make that regex work directly on `ElemMatch`, though, I can't match the overloads.

```
// Doesn't compile: cannot convert BsonRegularExpress to IMongoQuery.
Query.ElemMatch ("categories", new BsonRegularExpression (new Regex (someSearch, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)));
```

Is there some method for converting a `BsonRegularExpression` into an `IMongoQuery` object directly?

Or is there some `Matches` syntax for applying the current iterated element in a list that would allow for a hybrid of the two? Something like this made up code.

```
// Doesn't work: totally making this up.
Query.ElemMatch ("categories", Query.Matches (iteratorElement, new BsonRegularExpression (new Regex (someSearch, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)));
```

I was hoping to avoid just sending a raw string into the MongoDB driver, both so I can escape the search string from injection and so the code isn't littered with magic string field names (instead limited to just the `BsonElement` attribute on the DB model fields).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be 100% what you are after (as it's not IQueryable); but it does achieve what you want (strongly typed regex filtering of a collection, using Linq):

```
        var videosMongo = DbManager.Db.GetCollection<Video> ("videos");
        var videosCollection = videosMongo.AsQueryable<Video> ();
        videosMongo.Insert (new Video () {
            Id = new ObjectId (),
            Tags = new string[]{ "one", "two", "test three", "four test", "five" },
            Name = "video one"
        });
        videosMongo.Insert (new Video () {
            Id = new ObjectId (),
            Tags = new string[]{ "one", "two", "test three", "four test", "five" },
            Name = "video two"
        });
        videosMongo.Insert (new Video () {
            Id = new ObjectId (),
            Tags = new string[]{ "one", "two" },
            Name = "video three"
        });
        videosMongo.Insert (new Video () {
            Id = new ObjectId (),
            Tags = new string[]{ "a test" },
            Name = "video four"
        });


        var videos = videosCollection.Where (v => v.Name == "video four").ToList ();

        var collection = DbManager.Db.GetCollection<Video> ("videos");
        var regex = new BsonRegularExpression ("test");
        var query = Query<Video>.Matches (p => p.Tags, regex);
        var results = collection.Find (query).ToList ();
```

I worked this out by using the excellent resource here : http://www.layerworks.com/blog/2014/11/11/mongodb-shell-csharp-driver-comparison-cheat-cheet

Comment: In this case, the only change I made was to use the `BsonRegularExpression` overload that takes a standard .NET Regex object (`new BsonRegularExpression (new Regex (search, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))`), but other than that, it was exactly what I was trying to do.